# Default IIS page displaying

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2012, web-hosting

I have hosted my website in IIS 8 and I assigned a host name to that site. If i trigger my host name in browser, it show me the default IIS 8 page.

please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance 
Jey

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the path of the site? In IIS Manager -> Basic Settings there is a setting 'Physical Path', this should be set to the path of your web site.

Comment: Yeah i assigned path. I resolved because this is DNS server issue.